# Cannot read property of undefined of an apparently NOT undefined - SOLVED

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using a control of Telerik (AutoCompleteBox) which contains an embedded dropdown control that can be accessed through the property _dropDown. I am using the dropDownItemDataBound event to trigger the following code:

```
var autoComplete = $find("<%= RadAutoCompleteBox1.ClientID %>");
console.log(autoComplete._dropDown._items);
```

When I click over the [] in the console I get this (that is expected):

```
[]
0: b.RadAutoCompleteBox.DropDownItem
_attributes: c.AutoCompleteBoxAttributeCollection {_data: {…}, _keys: Array(0)}
_element: null
_template: null
_text: "Chevrolet TRAVERSE "
_value: "GM1"
```

Thus I supposed that I could do this:

```
var autoComplete = $find("<%= RadAutoCompleteBox1.ClientID %>");
console.log(autoComplete._dropDown._items[0]._text); // Chevrolet TRAVERSE
console.log(autoComplete._dropDown._items[0]._value); // GM1
```

Instead I get:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_text' of undefined**

It doesn't make sense to me because since autoComplete._dropDown._items is obviously an array (and it's NOT undefined!) I should be able to access it by indexing it and get the property contents. Not?

EDIT:

Following the suggestion of @ChrisG that mentioned that perhaps the arry was STILL empty when I tried to log the data to the console, I changed my code into the event to this (to give it a little time and see what happens):

```
waitAndDisplay();
    
function waitAndDisplay(timeout = 50) {
   setTimeout(function () {
      var autoComplete = $find("<%= RadAutoCompleteBox1.ClientID %>");
      console.log(autoComplete._dropDown._items[0]._text);
   }, timeout);
}
```

Indeed it **worked** however it doesn't seem to be a safe approach. Any idea on how to ENSURE that the data is fully loaded before to try to read it?

**SOLUTION:**

I was after the suggestion of @ChrisG on use a callback to data loaded and figured that I goofed in the documentation of the control because in fact there IS an event that triggers after the dropdown is fully loaded, so I will post the solution here. This way the callback function to be used is OnClientRequested and not the dropDownItemDataBound as I did initially:

```
function OnClientRequested(sender, eventArgs) {
   var myarray = eventArgs.get_data();
   console.log(myarray[0].Text);
   console.log(myarray[0].Value);
}
```

It will return the proper data.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that `autoComplete._dropDown._items` is still undefined when you try to log the item text. The brower console displays live objects that are changed when they populate. Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/moykp8x5/

Comment: Are you sure that `autoComplete._dropDown._items` actually has at least one element? Show us the ouput of `console.log(autoComplete._dropDown._items)`.

Comment: @Barthy That's what OP is doing; the problem is that the first line of the output, `[]` indicates that the array was empty at the time of the console.log call

Comment: Are you sure the item located at index zero is not undefined?

Comment: @ChrisG yeah I must be blind. I did read the question by completely disregarded the evidence. OP are the dropdown items fetched asynchronously?

Comment: @ChrisG, in fact you were absolutely right and I edited my code in the original post with a test I did. However how could in this case to ensure that the data will be fully loaded before trying to read it? I think that although the timeout is good as a test it's is absolutelly NOT safe as a solution. Any idea?

Comment: Usually there's the possibility to `await` or use a callback; one should never have to rely on a timeout.

Comment: ChrisG, that's it. It's solved! Thanks for putting a light over this! :-)